# Оптимизировать задачу на Python

Tags: python

```py
n, m = map(int, input().split())

costs = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

maxem = 0

for i in range(1, m + 1):
    left = i
    for c in costs:
        if left - c >= 0:
            left = left - c
    maxem = max(maxem, left)

print(maxem)
```

Вот код. Есть список некоторых чисел, по которым последовательно проходимся. И есть число, от которого нужно отнимать элементы этого списка. Число от 0 до m. Если элемент списка больше числа, просто его пропускаем. Нужно выбрать такое число из отрезка от 0 до m, чтобы после прохождения всего списка осталось наибольшее возможное значение.

Допустим список 5 4 1. Максимальное 10. Если возьмем 10, можно отнять и 5, и 4, и 1. Останется 0. Например, возьмем 8, сможем отнять 5, не сможем 4 и сможем 1. В конце останется 2. Это и будет максимальным.

Сделал втупую перебором, как это можно оптимизировать?

Answer (score 1):

Работайте сразу с интервалом возможных остатков от суммы *[low, high]*. Первоначально *low = 1*, *high = m*.

В цикле "вычитаем" из интервала число *c*:

- если *c ≤ low*, то новый интервал *[low - c, high - c]*.
- если *low < c ≤ high*, то новый интервал *[0, max(c - 1, high - с)]*.

  Числа из *[low, c - 1]* не меняются. Числа из *[c, high]* уменьшаются на *c*, что даёт *[0, high - c]*. Нам нужно объединение *[low, c - 1] ⋃ [0, high - c]*, поэтому такой новый интервал. Здесь используется что *low ≤ 1*, иначе множество значений может стать не одним интервалом и задача усложнится.
- если *high < c*, интервал не меняется.

Получится такой код:

```
_, m = map(int, input().split())

low = 1
high = m

for c in map(int, input().split()):
    if c <= low:
        low -= c
        high -= c
    elif c <= high:
        low = c
        high = max(c - 1, high - c)
print(high)
```